# cannot get the gedit autotab plugin to work

Tags: 12.04, unity, gedit, plugins

If you are trying to write python code inside of gedit, you probably want auto-tabbing. Meaning suppose you are writing a method, you type something like:

```
def foo():
```

Then hit enter. The cursor goes to the next line. You naturally hit tab to write code for the method

```
def foo():
    print 'foo'
```

So after print 'foo' if you hit enter, the cursor comes to the beginning of the line; it doesn't auto tab and appear under the `p` in `print`

So I googled for plugins, and I came up with [gedit-autotab](http://code.google.com/p/gedit-autotab/). But this one was developed when gnome2 was popular. Hence I googled to find out about how to install plugins on unity and took references from [here](http://nickhumphreyit.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-install-gedit-regexregexp-plugin.html). Basically it says we have to paste the downloaded stuff into:

```
~/.local/share/gedit/plugins
```

However I have downloaded gedit-autotab and copied the archive contents to the above folder. And it didn't work! How to get this fixed?

Comment: `gedit-autotab` won't work with Gnome 3.6. The feature you were apparently looking for is called "automatic indentation", so the title of the question is misleading. Care to edit?

Comment: There is a "modern gedits" fork here: https://github.com/kapouer/gedit-autotab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a default installation the automatic indentation feature of gedit is found in *Edit -> Preferences... -> Editor*:

[image]

Comment: Totally missed this one...thanx